# How to consecutively delete all rows until we reach the corresponding negative result

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like as given:
[image: Dataframe]

diff is the difference between values column. I need to delete all the rows between 5 and -5 , similarly 4 and -4. This is a sample dataset which I did. My real dataset has millions of rows. The correct records ideally have a difference that ranges between 0 - 1, however some false data present in the dataset gives a huge difference of 300, which after some records gives a difference of -300. in short, it follows the same pattern as this screenshot

In this small dataset, how can I achieve so that I can scale to big dataset.

Thanks

Comment: Is it right to assume that if you want to delete everything between 5 and -5 that in you larger dataset, they would come in pairs? In your sample set 5 is in index 4 and -5 is in index 6. Could another instance of 5 and -5 appear again in the larger dataset?

Comment: Yes, in larger dataset sometimes the diff is +231.563, followed by almost similar diff -231.055 at some point. similarly there may be +120.45...and -120.11..  In short,  this actually happens when the values column consecutively increment some data, but in the middle some other data comes which also keeps on incrementing followed by the previous data. Ex : a pattern like 670.11, 670,21, 670.31, 694.34, 694.44, 694.56, 670.41, 670.51. Here I need only the continuous records of 670 and not 694 ( which are wrong ones). There is also a pattern like  670.31, 694.34, 670.41, 694.44, 670.51.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
def drop_between(start_signal, end_signal):
  low_idx = df.loc[df['diff']==start_signal].index
  high_idx = df.loc[df['diff']==end_signal].index

  for l, h in zip(low_idx, high_idx):
    df.drop(index=np.arange(l,h+1), axis=0, inplace=True)

my_signals_list = [(5, -5), (4, -4)]
for s in my_signals_list:
  drop_between(*s)
```

Comment: I cannot hard code values, this is just an example, my actual dataframe has millions of rows with different extremes..  My actual column values will be something like Ex : a pattern like 670.11, 670,21, 670.31, 694.34, 694.44, 694.56, 670.41, 670.51. I need to extract only the consecutive rows of 670.... Please not I cannot hard-code anything in the code

Comment: You can change the one above to a function so it accepts a value as a signal to know where to start removing.

Comment: I don't have a pre-defined list of signal. It can vary. Is this possible with cumsum and shift?